# I can add a SharePoint Online library to a MS Teams channel, but what about Teams library to SharePoint?

Tags: file, sharepoint, channel

On MS Teams, I can go to the top of a Channel page and click "+" and add a SharePoint document library tab to that Channel.
Another guy added a File library tab to the Teams Channel. I want the files in the File library to be visible on SharePoint, so do I have to move the contents to a SharePoint library and then make that library accessible on the Teams Channel?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the files tab in teams is linked to General folder in the SharePoint document library. So you do not have to move the contents.

You could click open in Sharepoint button to visit in SharePoint

[image]

[image]